# Qt - Not all possible target environments can be supported due to missing compilers

Tags: qt, arm, clang, qt-creator, apple-silicon

I'm getting this error after upgrading to Qt 6.5.2 and Qt Creator 11.0.0 on my Mac under Preferences > Kits > Qt Versions:
Not all possible target environments can be supported due to missing compilers.

When I hover over "Not all possible...", it says:
The following ABIs are currently not supported:
arm-darwin-generic-mach_o-64bit

When I click on Details, under the ABI section, it says:
×86-darwin-generic-mach_o-64bit
arm-darwin-generic-mach_o-64bit
Which explains why such an error may be displayed.

The problem: projects are being built and compiled, but Qt Creator cannot identify any Qt-related files or identifiers.
It all worked well on Qt Creator 10.0.2 and Qt 6.4.2.

macOS 12.6.8
Xcode 14.2

Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0

Intel-based 2016 MacBook Pro

Explanatory screenshots [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lGiatt1TVH6G3AquBhcztlXsjqdxyONe/view?usp=drivesdk).

The same question has been asked on [Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/147166/not-all-possible-target-environments-can-be-supported-due-to-missing-compilers?_=1690449816340).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As followed up on the aforementioned [topic](https://forum.qt.io/topic/147166/not-all-possible-target-environments-can-be-supported-due-to-missing-compilers/5?_=1690704193071) on Qt Forum and with the help of [@hskolgund](https://forum.qt.io/user/hskoglund) there, I had to reinstall Xcode Command Line Tools.

First, I deleted it by `sudo rm -fR /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and installed by `xcode-select --install`. The newly installed Clang compiler now contained support for arm64 and so the initial "Not all possible..." problem was resolved, but a new one [re-emerged](https://forum.qt.io/topic/147297/clang-code-model-doesn-t-work-when-using-cmake).